# How to load ajax response in to iframe instead of div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe

I am loading ajax response to div but now i want to load it to middle iframe i tried the following but it never work! could you guys tell me what i am doing wrong ? Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

    $(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
    setInterval(function() {
    //$('#divToRefresh').load('./doit.php');

    $("#iframe").attr('blank.php','./doit.php'); //change url
    }, 20000); 
    });
    // ]]></script>


<iframe name="top" src="blank.php" id="top"  scrolling="no" noresize frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="79"></iframe>
<iframe NAME="middle" src="blank.php" id="middle" noresize frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="238" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
<iframe NAME="foot" src="blank.php" id="foot"  scrolling="no"  noresize frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" width="100%" height="200"></iframe>


<div id="divToRefresh">Loading ...</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attr is used to replace an attribute, you are not stating which attribute to replace you are stating the value of that attribute

it should be something like:

```
$("#middle").attr('src','./doit.php'); //change url
```

However this is not ajax... it is plain simple iframe technique
in other words the $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });  is not used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You ajax call is wrong or incomplete. If you want to fetch data using ajax; you should read the [**jQuery.ajax() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). But first, **[this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/534632/WhatplusisplusAJAX-3f)**.

Also read the [**.attr() documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). The first parameter should be the attribute name and the second should be the value.

But; it looks like you want to redirect the page in that `iframe`.
If that's the case, your selector should be `#middle`:

```
$("#middle").attr("src", "./doit.php");
```

You can also do it via a link (without jQuery or javascript) like this:

```
<a href="./doit.php" target="middle">Do It!</a>
```

Comment: you mean calling the php to get fresh data the way i did  is not ajax ? then how is the better way to call doit.php every 20 seconds and load it to iframe ?

Comment: The only thing related to AJAX is the line where you use `$.ajaxSetup` but then, you do nothing with it and try to redirect an iframe. If your PHP makes an AJAX request, we wouldn't know since you didn't include it in the code provided. Your `setInterval` approach is OK but not the code inside it.